# Selecting all entries in a table before this month

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I've been trying different solutions but none seem to return the same values as I get from excel.

I want to return all the items from a table where the entries in a column are before the current month value. So, if this month is January 2020, return the values before January 2020.

Ideally it's going in a function where I am passing in the number of months back

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE date_column < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH).
```

I've tried so many variations, I've now confused myself! Lots of the times it's returning NULL, and this variation returns a value, but it's missing some values.

Comment: If you want to get only results from last month, you can try `date_column BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-31'` or easier approach `YEAR(date_column) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(date_column) = MONT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all values before the start of the current month, you can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_name 
WHERE date_column <  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m'), '-01')
```

You can then shift the boundary with date arithmetic: for example, to get data before the start of the *previous* month:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_name 
WHERE date_column <  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, '%Y-%m'), '-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Comment: This second solution also allows me to pass into it the number of months back I want to go from which lets me use it in a function. Awesome. Ta!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using just `date` arithmetic:

```
where date_column < curdate() + interval (1 - day(curdate())) day
```

If you want to use date functions (and preclude the use of indexes), you can use the more explicit:

```
where year(date_column) < year(curdate()) or
      (year(date_column) = year(curdate()) and month(date_column) < month(date_column))
```

If there are no future dates, this can be simplified to:

```
where year(date_column) < year(curdate()) or
      month(date_column) < month(date_column)
```

Comment: Really useful. The first one did the job. Thanks!